# How to convert these pipe with tar pigz commands into ssh remote execute?

Tags: linux, bash

Linux command, manually open terminal and execute command, no issue
Yes. I want to put something like this:
    (nc -l 8400 | pigz -d | tar xvf - )&

How to make it run by ssh remote execute?

it works if terminal is keeping open.
but it won't work if I exit terminal after typing the command or execute remotely through ssh client '(nc -l 8400 | pigz -d | tar xvf - )& '

When I execute command through ssh, error message is " tar: This does not look like a tar archive "

ok. I fixed the problem by myself based on help from Jonathan and blog ( http://pen-testing.sans.org/blog/2013/05/06/netcat-without-e-no-problem/comment-page-1/ )

on client: mkfifo /tmp/pipe0

```
ssh -f client " bash -c ' mkfifo /tmp/pipe0; cd /tmp/test; ( /bin/sh 0</tmp/pipe0 | nc -l 8400 | pigz -d | tar xf - )'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. What do you mean "it won't work due to stdin error for tar command"?  Is the input to `pigz` a valid compressed file (in a stream from `nc`?  Is the output from `pigz` a valid tar file?  What exactly is the error you get from `tar`?  My guess is it says something about 'invalid file format'.

Comment: Also, are you really running on a system where `tar` can't handle the decompression itself?  You should probably take `pigz` out of the pipeline since it can't really use multiple threads when decompressing. On the face of it, using `(nc -l 8400 | tar -xvf - ) &` should do the job without involving `pigz` at all.

Comment: Removing pigz didn't fix the problem.  Both (nc -l 8400 | pigz -d | tar xvf - )&  and (nc -l 8400 | tar xvf - )& ' are working if terminal open. I think "-" means /dev/stdin in "tar xvf -" . If in ssh mode,  tar command can't recognize "-" or /dev/stdin any more.

Comment: OK — or, not really OK, but we'll go with what you say for the time being.  Have you captured the output from `nc` and the output from `pigz`?  As in: `(nc -l 8400 | tee nc.output | pigz -d | tee pigz.output | tar -xvf -)`?  When you run `file nc.output pigz.output`, what does it say?  How are you writing to port 8400?  What are you writing to port 8400?

Comment: hi, Jeff: Thanks. I don't think port 8400 matters. It can be any port once firewall opened this port. server side can be any file or directory. What I did on server side: tar cv message.log | pigz | nc client_node_name 8400 .  nothing from nc.output or pigz.output when running (nc -l 8400 | tee nc.output | pigz -d | tee pigz.output | tar -xvf -)

Comment: If there's nothing in either `nc.output` or `pigz.output`, then your problem is that the data is not being received over the wire.  Looking at your generating command, I'd expect to use: `tar -cvf - message.log | tee tar.output | pigz -c | tee pigz.output | nc client_node_name 8400` in debugging mode (as we're in at the moment), dropping the `tee` commands when we've resolved the problems.  I've not experimented with `tar` and no explicit `-f` option, but it used (once upon an æon or two ago) to write to a tape device (a _long_ time ago) by default. Similarly with `pigz` and no options.

Comment: _[...Continuing...]_ However, it appears that `tar` now writes to standard output by default (a sensible change of default — and presumably reads from standard input by default too), and `pigz` does compress standard input to standard output when given no arguments.  So, the original command should work — add the `tee` commands to check that you're getting data.  Have you got a network monitor program around (Wireshark, or something similar)? Have you checked that the data is going over the wire?  The empty `nc.output` file on the receiver is strongly indicative of a problem before that stage.

Comment: I don't think any data transmission problem here. if use only (nc -l 8400 >test.tar.gz), it works. I think the problem is, in background without terminal, tar or pigz command couldn't get data from /dev/stdin.  or pipe doesn't work under this case.

Comment: I think it incredibly improbable that either `tar` or `pigz` is affected in the slightest by being in the background.  I might be prepared to believe `nc` behaves differently, but the other two are in a pipeline exactly as normal and they won't open `/dev/stdin` (they'll simply read from standard input, and `pigz` will write to standard output).  If `nc.output` on the receiving end is empty, the problem is in `nc`.  I'm surprised, but based on the evidence you're giving me, that's the conclusion I have to come to. Have you added the `-v` option to `nc` on each end? Does it reveal anything?

Comment: Does `(nc -v -l 8400 > test.tar.gz) &` work?  If it does, then `(nc -v -l 8400 | tee test.tar.gz > /dev/null) &` should work too.

Comment: ok. just tested. You are right. some problem with nc command. based on this blog, http://pen-testing.sans.org/blog/2013/05/06/netcat-without-e-no-problem/comment-page-1/ I fixed the problem partially by: ssh -f client " bash -c 'mkpipe /tmp/pipe0;  /bin/sh 0</tmp/pipe0 | nc -l 8400 >/tmp/test1.tar.gz'"  - still need to get some way let pigz and tar working under pipe

Comment: ok. finally every thing works now with modified version: ssh -f client " bash -c 'cd /tmp/test; ( /bin/sh 0</tmp/pipe0 | nc -l 8400 | pigz -d | tar xf - )'

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like

```
(nc -l 8400 | pigz -d | tar xvf - )&
```

However, if you just want to send tar'ed, compressed data to your remote machine, to get it extracted there, you can use ssh without nc:

```
cat input.tar.gz | ssh remote.host "cd destDir; gzip -d | tar xf -"
```

(`pigz -d` should work as well)

Comment: if use ; then we need to wait the whole file transfer done before tar the file. if the file is super big, pigz and tar from pipe will save time and more efficient.